# How to change the baudrate in c/c++

Tags: c++, serial-port, uart, beagleboneblack

Hello I need advice of how correctly to change the baud rate of the UART port in the middle of the program.

To establish communication with my desired slave I need to send the so called "break field" which consists of 13-26 (MIN 11) LOW BITS, on UART as I think it's not achievable as before and after every 8 bits UART adds start & stop bit. I had an idea of achieving it by manipulating the baud-rates send break field at 9600Bauds followed by the 19200Baud speed. 
But I'm unable to see difference between baudrates on the oscilloscope. So I suppose I do it in the wrong way.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <termios.h> 
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <unistd.h> 
#include <fcntl.h> 
#include <sys/signal.h> 
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


#define BAUDRATE9600 B9600
#define BAUDRATE19200 B19200
#define PORT "/dev/ttyO4"
#define _POSIX_SOURCE 1
main() 
{ 
int fd, c; 
struct termios oldtio, newtio, midtio; 


fd = open(PORT, O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NONBLOCK);
if (fd <0) { perror(PORT); exit(-1); }


tcgetattr(fd, &oldtio); /* save current port settings */ 


/* set new port settings for canonical input processing */ 
midtio.c_cflag = BAUDRATE9600 | CS8 | CLOCAL | CSTOPB ;
midtio.c_iflag = IGNPAR | ICRNL;
midtio.c_oflag = 0;
midtio.c_lflag = ICANON;

newtio.c_cflag = BAUDRATE19200 | CRTSCTS | CS8 | CLOCAL | CREAD;
newtio.c_iflag = IGNPAR | ICRNL;
newtio.c_oflag = 0;
newtio.c_lflag = ICANON;


tcsetattr(fd, TCSANOW, &midtio);
char break[] = {0x00}; // break field (0000 0000)

c = write (fd, break, sizeof(break));

tcsetattr(fd, TCSANOW, &newtio);  


char sync [] = {0x55}; 
char PID [] = {0xE2}; 
char data [] = {0xAA}; 
char data1 [] = {0xA5};  
char check [] = {0xAF}; 
c = write (fd, sync, sizeof(sync));
c = write (fd, PID, sizeof(PID));
c = write (fd, data, sizeof(data));
c = write (fd, data1, sizeof(data1));
c = write (fd, check, sizeof(check));

/* restore old port settings */ 
 tcsetattr(fd,TCSANOW,&oldtio);
}
```

I have tried it also by setting baudrates in different way as well:

```
cfsetispeed(&midtio, B9600)
cfset0speed(&midtio, B9600)

cfsetispeed(&newtio, B19200)
cfset0speed(&newtio, B19200)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I need to send the so called "break field"

If the goal is to send a "break", then you've asked an XY question with *"How to change the baudrate in c/c++"*.  You cannot generate a break condition by manipulating the baud rate.  You would need a baud rate of less than 32 baud to achieve a quarter-second break.

A break condition can be sent on the serial link by using the **TCSBRK** command in an [ioctl()](http://linux.die.net/man/4/tty_ioctl).

BTW your serial port initialization code does not conform to best programming practices.  You should always be testing the return codes from system calls.  The elements of the *termios* structure should not be directly assigned, but rather just the individual bits should be modified.  Refer to a guide such as [this](http://www.cmrr.umn.edu/~strupp/serial.html#modem).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the TCSBRK send a stream of low bits for a 0.25 -0.5 seconds is it possible to set the limit on how long it will send a break. I need 13-26 low bits and at Baudrate of 9600 it should take about 1.3ms - 2.6ms.

Comment: Consult the `ioctl()` man page (the web link is in the answer).  There are other `ioctl()`s to turn on and off the break condition.